# Issue Launching Grails project to cloudfoundry

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

I am having a problem launching my (grails) project to cloud foundry.  I have already launched with `cf-push`, but I keep getting this error

```
I/O error: Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

when I run `cf-update`.

I also cannot see my log files with `cf-crashlogs`. I get this in the terminal window:

```
grails> cf-crashlogs
|   Checking for available resources:.....
```

And if I try to access the page I get a `404 Not Found` page.

Did I completely miss something?  has anyone else seen this or know how fix this issue?

Comment: hi Eric, is this problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

please check which version of the cf grails plugin were you using. try listing the plugin updates with this command:

```
grails list-plugin-updates
```

after that try to get cloud foundry connection info by:

```
grails cf-info
```

i suppose you know how to configure the login info, all the configure properties are listed here: http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-cloud-foundry/docs/manual/guide/3%20Configuration.html

to access your app log, the most commonly used command is

```
grails cf-logs [destination] [--appname] [--instance] [--stderr] [--stdout] [--startup]
```

hope that helps.

Comment: so the plugin is the most recent.  also when I run cf-info I get:  Error 
There was an error retrieving logs/stderr.log, please try again

Comment: no, cf-info is not supposed to retrieve the stdout/err.log. it shows the cf target and the login info your project is using. are you sure you actually ran cf-info? please paste the detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to test Cloud Foundry long time ago. Don't remember but also had some issues which I couldn't overcome using default tool.
However then I used [the Cloud Foundry Integration](http://grails.org/plugin/cloud-foundry).
As I mentioned it was some time ago, so I won't help with the details, but the plugin worked as expected and I was able to deploy. Maybe you will success with it too :)